# Submitting AJAx form in a php loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been searching for 3 weeks and can't seem to solve this issue. I am new to Ajax but have figured out how to use it to submit a single form. I am trying to learn how to use Ajax to submit a form in a php loop however. I think it has something to do with individual id's but I'm not sure how to create them. My programming below only allows me to submit the first form. Does anybody know how to fix this so I can submit the forms in the loop? Thank you very much in advance for your help

Here is my code so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<?php include 'dbconnection.php';?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function chk()
{
 var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
 var dataString='name='+ name;
 $.ajax({
  type:"post",
  url: "dataInsert.php",
  data:dataString,
  cache:false,
  success:function(phtml){
   $('.msg1').html(phtml);
  }
  
 });
 return false;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT distinct first_name from people " );
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>
</br> <?php  echo$row["first_name"];   ?>

<form>
<input type="text" id="name">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="return chk()">

</form>
<p id="msg" class="msg1"></p>
<?php
}

?>
</body>

</html>
```

dataInsert.php

```html
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
echo "Response: ".$name;
?>



<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';
  $first_name = $_POST['name'];
 
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO people(first_name)
   VALUES ('$first_name')");
   
 ?>
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since id's must be unique through out the HTML-document, you need to give each field a different id. That goes for *all* id's on element (like the `msg` as well) When that's done, you can pass that id to your method, making your js-function reusable.

The loop (see the comments to see the changes):

```
<?php
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT distinct first_name from people " );

// Initiate a counter variable
$i = 1;

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>
</br> <?php  echo$row["first_name"];   ?>

<form>
<!-- Append the counter to the ID -->
<input type="text" id="name<?= $i ?>">
<br/>

<!-- Send just the current counter to your method -->
<input type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="return chk('<?= $i ?>')">

</form>
<!-- Append the counter to the message ID -->
<p id="msg<?= $i ?>" class="msg1"></p>
<?php
    // Increment the counter
    $i++;
}

?>
```

The js-function (again, see the comments to see the changes):

```
// Add the counter id as an argument, which we passed in the code above
function chk(id)
{
    // Append the counter id to the ID to get the correct input
    var name=document.getElementById('name' + id).value;
    var dataString='name='+ name;
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "dataInsert.php",
        data:dataString,
        cache:false,
        success:function(phtml){
            // Instead of using the class to set the message, use the ID,
            // otherwise all elements will get the text. Again, append the counter id.
            $('#msg' + id).html(phtml);
        }

    });
    return false;
}
```

Now you should be able to send all forms seperate from eachother.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly now. Thanks for the comments as well it makes it really easy to understand.

Comment: Today I have been trying to add another input to my form e.g <input type="text" id="surname<?= $i ?>"><br/><input type="text" id="class<?= $i ?>"> I have tried to a large amount of things to get this information to post. Are you able to show me how to modify the ajax so all of these can post? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @bevan7 If the above answer did help you with the original question, feel free to accept it. If you have a new question, please create a new question. This is so the history of the Q&A is intact for future visitors.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I've deleted the last one and added a new question. Thanks for your help.